# Ease Of Twitter Bootstrap For An Already Developed Website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a website built in Rails that is just falling apart in different browsers. Is Twitter Bootstrap something I can use to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an excellent way of making websites look good on different browsers.

JQuery is an excellent way of making your websites interact well on different browsers.

Next time, I'd suggest asking a more code-focused question and telling us what you've already tried. People on Stack Overflow like to know that you've tried to solve the problem yourself before coming here.

Comment: I hired a developer and he tried to make the website look right in different environments. Still has issues. Can I hire you to fix the thing? If so, how much would you charge me and what would you do?

Comment: I would private message you, but I could not find that button.

Comment: I'm not the right person for that job. There are other websites for that exact kind of thing -- what you're really after here is a web designer. I'd suggest finding such a website and looking for a designer there.